# SharePoint Online Management Shell : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, authorization

So I'm using tutorial from here : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161372.aspx

But when I tried to connect, there is an error as above. I have set my credential as global administrator. I also checked on my O365 admin -> user, my account registered as global administrator. So why am I still unauthorized to access my SPO using SPO Management Shell?

Below are my code based on tutorial from msdn

```
$adminUPN="intanpuspita@my365trial.onmicrosoft.com"
$orgName="my365trial"
$userCredential = Get-Credential -UserName $adminUPN -Message "Type the password."
Connect-SPOService -Url http://$orgName-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $userCredential
```

Comment: could you please share the your commands, how you trying to connect?

Comment: and which site you trying to connect?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE yup i already added the code in my questions

Comment: i see your Admin site url is Http...is it typo? also instead of using the $orgname just type directly url

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE No its not a typo. I'm just following the instruction in link above, and if i remove the Http it will give me another error. And also I tried to type my url directly, but it still give me unauthorized error

Comment: try with this url https://$orgName-admin.sharepoint.com or https://my365trial-admin.sharepoint.com, please share the output

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE it works using https.. I tried using https in the first try but it display an error, so i changed it into http. But it works now!! Weird. But thanks :)

Comment: great, I added that as anwser for community benifit, Please upvote and mark it as answer so that all gets benfits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your command looks like you are trying to connect using the http url. In SPO, I believe it is always https.Please use the below script( with https).

```
$adminUPN="intanpuspita@my365trial.onmicrosoft.com"
$orgName="my365trial"
$userCredential = Get-Credential -UserName $adminUPN -Message "Type the password."
Connect-SPOService -Url **httpS://**$orgName-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $userCredential
```